# Why is this concurrent code slower than the serial code? (Go)

Tags: performance, go, concurrency, benchmarking, goroutine

I wanted to try using a concurrent solution to problem 206 (Reverse a Linked List) on LeetCode, so I wrote this:

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev, temp *ListNode
    cur, ch := head, make(chan bool)

    for cur != nil {
        temp = cur.Next
        go func(cur *ListNode, prev *ListNode) {
            cur.Next = prev
            ch <- true
        }(cur, prev)
        <-ch
        cur, prev = temp, cur
    }

    return prev
}
```

my previous, serial solution was this:

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var cur, prev *ListNode = head, nil
    for cur != nil {
        prev, cur, cur.Next = cur, cur.Next, prev
    }

    return prev
}
```

Here are the benched functions:

```
func BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent(b *testing.B) {
    slice := generateLinkedListSlice(1000000, b.N) //generates slice of Linked Lists

    b.ResetTimer()
    var cur, prev, temp *ListNode
    var ch chan bool
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        fmt.Println("test")
        cur, ch = slice[i], make(chan bool, 5000)

        for cur != nil {
            temp = cur.Next

            go func(cur *ListNode, prev *ListNode) {
                cur.Next = prev
             ch <- true
            }(cur, prev)

            <-ch

            cur, prev = temp, cur
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial(b *testing.B) {
    slice := generateLinkedListSlice(1000000, b.N) //generates slice of Linked Lists

    b.ResetTimer()
    var cur, prev *ListNode
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        fmt.Println("test")
        cur = slice[i]
        for cur != nil {
            prev, cur, cur.Next = cur, cur.Next, prev
        }
    }
}
```

I benched both of them and got these results:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: benchmark-tests
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent-6               602           1812494 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent-6               673           1767912 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent-6               680           1557250 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent-6               771           1896961 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListConcurrent-6               634           1874298 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial-6                332670             33707 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial-6                308980             34237 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial-6                278793              3735 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial-6                326935              3989 ns/op
BenchmarkReverseLinkedListSerial-6                279200              4182 ns/op
```

Is there something wrong with my concurrent solution, or is it some other problem, like an overhead?

Comment: Your solution isn't really concurrent. You start a goroutine and then do nothing but wait until it is finished.

Comment: That being said, swapping a few pointers is incredibly fast. Any overhead from trying to make this concurrent is going to dwarf the time it takes to do the work.

Answer (score 4):

There is some overhead to:

- starting a goroutine
- sending a value over a channel

That overhead must be justified by doing "enough" work in parallel. Multiple CPUs can cut down the time it takes to do a task if the task can be split well. But the reduction of time it takes to do the task must outweigh the communication (channel) and setup (go routines) overhead.

In your example, you are not doing significant work in parallel. All the goroutine does is `cur.Next = prev`. If instead you had `cur.Next = someHeavyOperation(prev)`, things would be different.

Next issue with the example is that the main routine does nothing but wait for the goroutine to return. Effectively that only puts the work on another routine (with all the overhead mentioned above) but then doesn't utilize the CPU of the main routine. Meaning there is no parallel usage of the 2 goroutines. Only one routine is working at a time.

Comment: There is overhead to starting a goroutine and sending a value over a channel, but I (and most engineers I know) wouldn't call it "significant". It's more than zero but it's not a lot.

Comment: Thx. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: Oh, so if I have 6 cores, and create 5 additional goroutines from the main one, they won't spread out to other cores? Like, the main one will use a core, and 4 others will be stuck waiting until the 1st additional goroutine finishes?

Comment: Sure they will spread out to other cores. But usually a go server has way more goroutines than it has cores. Apart from that, goroutines still need to wait for other things apart from a core being available. For example waiting for a http call to return or a database to answer. Or like in the code above a channel that it needs to wait for until another routine has written something to it.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, I see the error in my code, thanks